# R split by group and create new columns

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-manipulation, reshape2

I'm trying to split a data frame from long to wide format by converting selected rows to columns. Here is the current general long-format structure:

```
data_long <- data.frame(
  id = c("kelp","kelp","fish","fish","beach","beach","kelp","kelp","fish","fish","beach","beach"),
  desig = c("mpa","reference","mpa","reference","mpa","reference","mpa","reference","mpa","reference","mpa","reference"),
  indicator = c("density","density","density","density","density","density","biomass","biomass","biomass","biomass","biomass","biomass"),
  
  n = c(1118,1118,1118,1118,1118,1118,1118,1118,1118,1118,1118,1118), 
  m = c(0.35, 4.28, 1.16, 106.35, 13.44,0.63,0.35, 4.28, 1.16, 106.35, 13.44,0.63), 
  sd = c(1.19, 8.48, 4.25, 118, 31.77,2.79,1.19, 8.48, 4.25, 118, 31.77,2.79)
  
)
data_long
```

I want to keep id and indicator, split by "desig",and move "n", "m", and "sd" into new columns. The final data frame structure I'm trying to obtain is:

```
data_wide <- data.frame(
  id = c("kelp","fish","beach","kelp","fish","beach"),
  indicator = c("density","density","density","biomass","biomass","biomass"),
  
  mpa.n = c(1118,1118,1118,1118,1118,1118), 
  mpa.m = c(0.35, 4.28, 1.16, 106.35, 13.44,0.63), 
  mpa.sd = c(1.19, 8.48, 4.25, 118, 31.77,2.79),
  reference.n = c(1118,1118,1118,1118,1118,1118),
  reference.m = c(0.35, 4.28, 1.16, 106.35, 13.44,0.63),
  reference.sd = c(1.19, 8.48, 4.25, 118, 31.77,2.79)
  
)
data_wide
```

I can't seem to get this right using reshape2. Any suggestions?

Comment: I guess some values in 'data_wide' based on 'data_long' is found in wrong columns

Answer (score 1):

We may use `pivot_wider`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
pivot_wider(data_long, names_from = desig, 
     values_from = c(n, m, sd), names_glue = "{desig}.{.value}") %>%
  select(id, indicator, starts_with("mpa"), starts_with('reference'))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 8
  id    indicator mpa.n mpa.m mpa.sd reference.n reference.m reference.sd
  <chr> <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>
1 kelp  density    1118  0.35   1.19        1118        4.28         8.48
2 fish  density    1118  1.16   4.25        1118      106.         118   
3 beach density    1118 13.4   31.8         1118        0.63         2.79
4 kelp  biomass    1118  0.35   1.19        1118        4.28         8.48
5 fish  biomass    1118  1.16   4.25        1118      106.         118   
6 beach biomass    1118 13.4   31.8         1118        0.63         2.79
```

Comment: Excellent and instantaneous! Thank you!